# How do I pull a field in to a report from an associated record ( Accounting Seed )

Tags: reporting, account, record

I have a salesforce report ( Accounting Seed ) that includes a number of fields. When you click on the actual entry, you can get details including a reference to an other associated record ( it is linked to the entry, and you can click on that link ). I want to be able to pull a field from the **Associated Record** into my report, but I cant figure out how to do that. When I try to customize the report, it's not listed as a field that I can pull in.

Comment: Related: [Salesforce report relationships](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/85174/102)

Comment: How are the two records related?  Is one the parent of the other?  Is it a lookup relationship?

Answer (score 1):

I am a Developer at Accounting Seed. If your issue is still unresolved could you log a case at: https://support.accountingseed.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

I would be happy to help look at the Accounting Seed report that you are trying to customize.